# How can I use a game controller in BGE?

Tags: game-engine

How can I use a Bluetooth game controller as an input device for a game in Blender. I have tried what I can think of but I can't get it to work.

Comment: It would help to know what kind as you may have other gamers that could answer. That being said if it remaps to keyboard keys, that would be the easiest, because then you could just use trap the keyboard events.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native support to that kind of device.

If it comes with a joystick driver you can use the joystick sensor.